# Import sequence of positions as animation

Tags: animation, import

I'm trying to make a game and as any game requires, it needs animation.

I wrote a piece of software that can track a marker in 3D coordinates using cameras and save it into a file.

Is it possible to transfer those sequence of 3D positions to some object of blender and make it move? What kind if format it expects?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not the answer to your question, just some thoughs - does that mean that you'd like game engine to get 3d model animation as it's shown in the file where marker position is captured ? If so I don't *think* it's done like that; it maybe easier (and much often done like that) to rig the model and animate it as usual, save several animations (walk, run etc.) into several actions and feed those to game engine.

Comment: Well, here is what I want: given a video of a person ( from multiple cameras), create the rigging and the animation for that video. I think handmade animations may be very time consuming for me once I have no experience with that. I rather make it automatic. Once it is done, I can make a lot of animations with minimal effort.